# Clear Django cache for certain app or page

Tags: django, caching

Is there any possibility to clear cache for certain app in django or for certain page?
I've tried to find it but in vain.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What kind of cache? Back-end (i.e. django.core.cache) or front-end (browser cache), if back-end: per-page cache (as per CommonMiddleware) or low-level cache via the django.core.cache API?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like this might help you..

```
    from django.core.cache import get_cache, DEFAULT_CACHE_ALIAS
from django.utils.cache import get_cache_key, _generate_cache_header_key, _generate_cache_key
from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse
from django.http import HttpRequest
from django.conf import settings

def expire_cache(path, args=[], cache_name=None, isview=True, lang_code=None, method='GET'):
    if cache_name is None:
        cache_name = DEFAULT_CACHE_ALIAS

    cache = get_cache(cache_name)
    key_prefix = settings.CACHES[cache_name].get('KEY_PREFIX', '')

    request = HttpRequest()
    if isview:
        request.path = reverse(path, args=args)
    else:
        request.path = path

    language_code = lang_code or getattr(settings, 'LANGUAGE_CODE')
    if language_code:
        request.LANGUAGE_CODE = language_code

    header_key = _generate_cache_header_key(key_prefix, request)

    if not header_key:
        return False

    headerlist = cache.get(header_key, None)
    if headerlist is not None:
        cache.set(header_key, None, 0)
        page_key = _generate_cache_key(request, method, headerlist, key_prefix)

        if not page_key:
            return False

        cache.set(page_key, None, 0)
    return True

expire_cache('apps.yourapp.views.function')
```

Comment: Unfortunately this snippet does not seem to work for Django 1.11, because `_generate_cache_header_key` calls `request`'s method `get_host()`, which in turn accesses  `request`'s `META['SERVER_NAME']`, which is not set thus yeilding `KeyError`.